# SyntaxError: invalid character for comparison operator

Tags: python

The following code I wrote as exercise is throwing me a SyntaxError:

```
username = input("Please enter your username: ")
#print(username)
lenght = len(username)
#print(lenght)
if len(username) ‹ 3:
    print("name must be at least 3 chars long!")
elif len(username) › 50:
    print("name can be a maximum of 50 chars!")
else:
    print("name looks ok.")
```

I get the following error:

```
    if len(username) ‹ 3:
                     ^
SyntaxError: invalid character in identifier
```

Could not find any similar issue, the exercise is based on online course. I would appreciate your help on this.

Comment: How exactly did you type that symbol? What program are you using to write your code?

Comment: It looks like you have your input settings set to something other than English, with a different `<` character. You need the actual ASCII `<`.

Comment: this seems like a good point, 3-days mac user here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's not a less-than sign, it's a ['SINGLE LEFT-POINTING ANGLE QUOTATION MARK' (U+2039)](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2039/index.htm).

Comment: Another similar error two lines down, with [SINGLE RIGHT-POINTING ANGLE QUOTATION MARK (U+203A)](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/203a/index.htm) instead of the greater-than sign.